# Python - How to get an average of two images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the first photo with a watermark, using code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("veidz.jpg")

alpha = 2.0
beta = -160

new = alpha * img + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("cleaned.png", new)
```

I get a second photo without a watermark, but it becomes sharper, so I have a question, is there any ways to apply a photo or something else to make the photo smoothed as the first, but without a watermark?

First photo:

[image: first photo]

Second photo:

[image: second photo]

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) if you feel the sharper response is too high, then you can use a pyramid type of method like this. The code inside works well.

https://github.com/arnaud-ramey/watermark_remover

[image]

(2) also you can use the watermark position as mask, then perform image smoothing to get text more nature